# Php variable que viene de un formulario de otra pagina no definida

Tags: php

tengo un formulario que tiene los datos de una cuenta y una pk foránea: identificacion, luego los envío a otra página para que haga el insert pero no me llegan las variables, isset me dice que no están definidas

```
if(isset($_GET['identificacion'])){
    $identificacion = $_GET['identificacion'];

    echo "<div align='center'>";    
            echo "<form action='cuenta_ingresada.php' method='post'>";

            echo "<label for='identificacion'>Identificacion </label> &nbsp;";       
            echo "<input type='text' name='identificacion' disabled value='". $identificacion . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='nro_cuenta'>Número de Cuenta </label> &nbsp;";       
            echo "<input type='text' name='nro_cuenta' ><br>";

            echo "<label for='fecha_apertura'>Fecha de Apertura </label> &nbsp;";        
            echo "<input type='text' name='fecha_apertura' ><br>";

            echo "<label for='sucursal_ciudad'>Sucursal Ciudad </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='sucursal_ciudad' ><br>";

            echo "<label for='tipo'>Tipo </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='tipo' ><br>";

            echo "<label for='saldo'>Saldo </label> &nbsp;";    
            echo "<input type='text' name='saldo' ><br>";


            echo "<div class='button'>";
            echo "<button type='submit' name='submit' value='actualizar'>Actualizar</button>";  
             //<button type="submit" name="submit">Guardar</button>     
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>"; 
            echo "</div>";
```

Y aquí llegan

```
if(isset($_POST['identificacion']) &&
        isset($_POST['nro_cuenta']) &&
        isset($_POST['fecha_apertura']) && 
        isset($_POST['sucursal_ciudad']) && 
        isset($_POST['tipo']) && 
        isset($_POST['saldo']))
    {             
        $nro_cuenta = $_POST['nro_cuenta'];
        $fecha_apertura = $_POST['fecha_apertura'];
        $sucursal_ciudad = $_POST['sucursal_ciudad'];
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
        $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
        $identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];         

        $insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_cuentas (nro_cuenta, fecha_apertura, sucursal_ciudad, tipo, saldo, identificacion) VALUES ('$nro_cuenta', '$fecha_apertura', '$sucursal_ciudad', '$tipo', '$saldo', '$identificacion')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los inputs que estan disabled no son transmitidos por POST.  Una solucion seria agregar un hidden input que contenga la misma informacion asi:

```
echo "<label for='identificacion'>Identificacion </label> &nbsp;";       
echo "<input type='text' disabled value='". $identificacion . "'><br>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='identificacion' value='". $identificacion . "'>;
```

Comment: Sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: Usé REQUEST EN EL QUE RECIBE LOS DATOS Y AHORA FUNCIONA. Te agradezco Alacfcm